# glueing 18 gauge s/s sheets to aluminum honeycomb backing

Tags: metal

I am involved in a project that requires gluing 18 gauge s/s sheets to 3/4" aluminum honeycomb panels.
what is the best contact adhesive to use that will withstand outside elements?
( extreme cold and extreme heat?)

Comment: something flexible: those materials have different rates of expansion.

Comment: you should clarify what "extreme" means.

Answer (score 1):

I would make test samples using Silicone I, Lexel, and metal epoxy to determine the best product for your application.

[Permatex Cold Weld](https://www.permatex.com/products/adhesives-sealants/epoxies/permatex-cold-weld-bonding-compound/) is the 2 part metal epoxy adhesive that I would try first. The other two are sealants and technically not adhesives, but they might still work.

[Permatex Steel Weld](https://www.permatex.com/products/adhesives-sealants/epoxies/permatex-steel-weld-epoxy/) is another option, it says it has a greater temperature range but sets in only 4 minutes so it might be hard to use.